# Disable index.php at url in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-routing

While using codeigniter, I am facing some difficulties. That's about the index.php file in URLs.

CodeIgniter serves all it's pages using `index.php`. So, our url's should look like following:

```
http://www.example.com/codeigniter/index.php/something
```

I want to remove the `index.php` from URLs by editing the `config.php` file and creating an .htaccess file. After changing the config from

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I am able to run my project without the index.php just like this:

```
http://www.example.com/codeigniter/something
```

So now, that link is working - but it's also working with the `index.php` fragment. I can also see the components with the `http://www.example.com/codeigniter/index.php/something` address.

My .htaccess file is :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now, I want to make my site only available without the `index.php` in my links. I don't want this site to run with the index.php file in the link. I want `http://www.example.com/codeigniter/something` to run perfectly and `http://www.example.com/codeigniter/index.php/something` not to run. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you paste your vhost configuration?

Comment: Sorry, what is vhost configuration? I am hosting my project in localhost with xampp

Answer (score 1):

you can try adding the following in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} codeigniter\/index\.php
RewriteRule codeigniter\/index\.php -[F]
```

Basically, this rule tells to return a forbidden response if the request contains codeigniter/index.php

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

put the code in your root folder htaccess.Please let me know if you face any problem

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule above the one that you already have:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /codeigniter/index\.php([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /codeignighter/%1 [L,R=301]
```

And it'll redirect requests that have `index.php` in it to the URL without it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a ? after index.php, so it works in all hostings. This is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /   maybe you don't need it, depends on the hosting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|humans\.txt|license\.txt|sitemap\.xml|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```